# Objects not colliding in 2D project

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I've set up a 2D project in Unity (4.3.4). It has a ball and ground. The ball is in the air.

To the ball I've added Box Collider 2D and Rigidbody 2D, standard values.

To the ground I've added Box Collider 2D.

When I run the game, the ball falls, but instead of stopping when hitting the ground, it continues and keep falling.

Where did I go wrong? By the tutorials this should simply work?

Comment: Check if one of the two colliders has the checkbox `isTrigger` checked. They should both be unchecked for collisions to work

Comment: YES, oh my g**! How silly. Put it in and I will accept it Steven!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if one of the two colliders has the checkbox `isTrigger` checked. They should both be unchecked for collisions to work. First time that happened to me it took me a whole day to figure it out xD